# Ubuntu does not boot in Oracle VirtualBox

Tags: boot, virtualbox, macosx

I am using Oracle VirtualBox 5.1.22 on macOS 10.12.5. I configured a Ubuntu 64 bit VM and installed Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS without any issues. When I reboot the VM to start the Ubuntu instance, I get a blank console window with a non-blinking cursor. I have let it sit there for over an hour and no change (See Image Below).

[image: Console Window]

I have checked the VirtualBox log and the last few lines show the following.

```
00:00:03.969706 Display::handleDisplayResize: uScreenId=0 pvVRAM=0000000000000000 w=720 h=400 bpp=0 cbLine=0x0 flags=0x0
00:00:03.969749 GUI: UIFrameBufferPrivate::NotifyChange: Screen=0, Origin=0x0, Size=720x400, Sending to async-handler
00:00:03.971483 VMMDev: Guest Log: BIOS: Booting from Hard Disk...
00:00:03.996305 GUI: UIMachineView::sltHandleNotifyChange: Screen=0, Size=720x400
00:00:03.996325 GUI: UIFrameBufferPrivate::handleNotifyChange: Size=720x400
00:00:03.996340 GUI: UIFrameBufferPrivate::performResize: Size=720x400, Directly using source bitmap content
```

The log shows it hanging on this and never changing. I have tried different VM configuration settings (ex. increased video memory, change chipset, etc) but have had no success. I also tried this on another Mac computer and got the same results.

Note, other VM installations work fine. Example CentOS.

Any ideas what might be going on?

Thank you

Comment: I suspect it has to do with the display driver. Boot into Grub, edit the startup command and use: nomodeset

Comment: Thanks WillemK. Your comment helped me find out what my issue was. I have provided the answer to this question. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

This is embarrassing but I had not installed Ubuntu with Grub. When I started over and installed it with Grub, the ubuntu VM booted with no issues.

Thanks